# executing a Windows command line program with system call in PHP

Tags: php, windows, command-line, system, call

I am trying to execute a program using a system call inside a php file like so:

```
$newname = 'C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\upload\test.ppt' ;
$program = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Softinterface, Inc\Convert PowerPoint\ConvertPPT"';
$input = ' /S "'. $newname .'"' 
$destination = ' /T "C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\upload\\"';
$switch = ' /C 18';
$command = $program . $input . $destination . $switch;
system($command);
```

For some reason, the program enters an infinite loop (the browser never stops loading). I have tried the command manually and it works perfectly (takes about 2 sec to complete) but when executing it with a php file doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out `$command` right before the system call just to make sure it's properly written?

Comment: @Kevin the $command is accurate

Comment: Hm. Not sure then. Are you sure that you're actually running a program? `'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Softinterface, Inc\Convert PowerPoint\ConvertPPT"` doesn't seem like you are (you're not executing a Windows binary). I'd expect you to have `someprogram.exe` at the end or something.

Comment: @Kevin, I added the .exe extension and still entering the infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

use the backtick(`) symbol to wrap around the command you want to run.

Comment: exec, single quote, string concatenation are all not needed.
just purely `backtick $command backtick`